# MSTest: execution order of tests within the same TestClass

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I need to enforce `TestClass` order when executing tests with MSTest.

The order of `TestClasses` and tests within each class can be random, but MSTest should not pick a test from another `TestClass` until it is done executing `ClassInitialize`, all tests in the class, and `ClassCleanup`.

I have global `AssemblyInitialize` and `AssemblyCleanup`, therefore the following does not work, because it initializes the assembly for each test:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:MyUnitTests.dll /resultsfile:report.trx /test:TestClass1 /test:TestClass2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029886/why-is-assemblyinitialize-and-assemblycleanup-being-called-twice-in-same-test), though it was not about test class execution order. Ordering tests can cause them to be brittle if the reason for the ordering is so that some sort of state can be setup/maintained. If this is the case with your tests, I would suggest instead writing them in a way that would be order-agnostic.

As regards your problem with the assembly-level code, a work around for the `AssemblyInitialize` and `AssemblyCleanup` can be as follows:

```
private int InitCount;

[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void Setup(TestContext context)
{
     if (InitCount++ == 0) {
         //Do Something
     }
}

[AssemblyCleanup]
public static void Teardown()
{
      if (--InitCount == 0) {
          //Do something
      }
}
```

Basically, you can force the assembly-level methods to fire only once.

Comment: thanks for the reply. this is not going to work for 2 different reasons: 1. every time the assembly is loaded it will get its own InitCount and initialize it every time/execute the code 2. AssemblyCleanup should be executed once after the LAST test is executed